# Google Compute Engine: lost exported env after closing SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-compute-engine

I have an instance on Google computer engine, and i have exported environment variable running `$ export my_token=my_token`. Everything is fine, it prints `my_token` running 
`$ echo $my_token`.

But after closing ssh connection and reconnect to my instance and I try again to run `echo $my_token`, it prints nothing. Therefore I guess I've  lost the exported environment variable after closing ssh.

- How can i keep my environment variable even after closing ssh on a Google Compute Engine Instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Compute Engine Instance it works exactly like any other Linux or Unix instance, from the Operating System point of view there is no difference.

### Explanation

- Setting an environment variable applies merely to the session, it is not persistent, each time you open a new shell (for example changing the user or connecting through ssh) you will lose the environment variable set in the previous one.

### Solution

To keep a value of an environment variable that will be set in each new shell you start, you could add the `export my_token=my_token` command to one of your shell's init files. 
For example `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

### Further References

- [Linux: Set Environment Variable](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/)
- [How do I set a user environment variable? (permanently, not session)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session)

Comment: well, because i don't want to save `my_token` in anywhere in gce, so i used command instead of using bash file. So can we have other ways to do without saving `my_token` on a file ? Saving token on a file can be a seurity problem.

Comment: You can place it in a file which can be accessed by your user only as for example .bashrc. Consider that the ssh keys are saved in `./ssh` folder and it is not considered a security issue.
If you want to store something and have it permanent also after a reboot I can see merely storing it into a file as a option

Comment: Therefore I do not see it really useful, but if you want to avoid it for any reason: you can "reconnect to a disconnected ssh session" When you first log in, run screen. You get another shell, run commands in that. If you're disconnected, the screen process keeps the terminal alive so that your shell and the processes it is running don't fall over. When you reconnect, run 'screen -r' to resume.